# Clicking on 'href' from <a> tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Hi i have the following in python

```
#Searching for company
varA = soup.find(Microsoft)
#Finding the <a> tag which contains href
#{<a data-deptmodal="true" href="https://someURL BASED ON COMPANY NAME">TEXT BASED ON COMPANY NAME</a>}
button = org.find_previous('a')
driver.find_element_by_tag_name(button).click()
```

and i get an error like

> TypeError: Object of type 'Tag' is not JSON serializable

How do I make the webdriver click on my href after i get the soup
please note that my href changes everytime i change the company name.

Comment: You don't need bs4, just click link based on Company name as `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Microsoft").click()` or `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Microsoft").click()` (if `"Microsoft"` is not the only string in link text)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing comment, `BeautifulSoup` is an *HTML parser*, it helps you to extract data from the HTML, it is not interacting with the page in any manner - it cannot, for instance, click the link.

If you need to click the link in the browser, do it via `selenium`. In your case the `.find_element_by_link_text()` (or `.find_element_by_partial_link_text()`) locator fits the problem really well:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Microsoft")
```

Documentation reference: [Locating Hyperlinks by Link Text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but my problem is its not always going to be microsoft. I want to make my code more dynamic for varying macros (companies). May I ask how would you do that?

Comment: @NewLearner what do you mean more dynamic? Could you elaborate? Thanks.